# Compare a variable with database entry

Tags: sql, database, variables, compare

I want to compare a variable with database entry, if they match to then pull out a bit of information from that account, if they don't then to end the query.

```
SELECT
    Account.ID AS ID,
    Account.Fax AS Fax,
    Account.MsgBalance AS MsgBalance
FROM
    Account
WHERE
    Account.ID = '{=Variables("AccountIDPull")}'
    AND Account.Fax LIKE '%{=Variables("NumberPull")}'
```

(i know this bit wont work but how do i do it?)
    THEN grab the Account.MsgBalance details
    ELSE End query

Comment: Where do your variables live? From where are you executing the SQL query?